# How can I add two types of object to object list and compare date between them?

Tags: java, android

I added 2 types of object to an object list. Now I want to compare date between them to sort them by date. Please show me how can I do that?

For example, the list is like this:

```
List<Object> mObjects = {ObjectType1,ObjectType2,ObjectType2,ObjectType1,ObjectType1....}
```

Comment: You have to override the equals method in your class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java

Comment: what you have tried so far ? did you aware about Comparator and Comparable in Java ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for this. Since you have different types of objects, you can use a common interface with a getter for date field.